# "[Do you know that] Kristina has found a job 'at last'/'finally'/'eventually'/'in the end'[?]"

Tags: phrase-usage

> 1. Kristina has found a job **at last**.
> 2. Kristina has found a job **finally**.
> 3. Kristina has found a job **eventually**.
> 4. Kristina has found a job **in the end**.

Apart the word order, on which I have doubts - especially in 2 and 3 cases -, which of the sentences above, if there is any,  sounds more natural in English language.

Also, which is better if I have to pose the sentences in interrogative form and, so, I have to start with:

> Do you know that Kristina ...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding all your examples, you can phrase them as a question but they should begin with "Did you know that..." not "Do you know that...".

To go through each of your examples:

> 1) Kristina has found a job at last.

This is perfectly fine, though I think the "at last" implies an exclamation mark at the end of the sentence, rather than the period.  (It sounds as if you're excited about the news: "Kristina has found a job at last!").  This is present tense, and means that Kristina has now found a job (and it took her quite a long time).

--

> 2) Kristina has found a job finally.

This is almost correct, the word order is just a bit off.  The correct way to phrase this would be:

> Kristina has finally found a job.

This has identical meaning to the first sentence, and is just fine to say.

--

> 3) Kristina has found a job eventually.

This isn't correct, *eventually* here doesn't fit with the present tense.  You could use it in past tense or to talk about possibilities in the future, though:

> Kristina found a job eventually.

Meaning in the past, after a good while of searching, Kristina did find a job.

> Kristina will find a job eventually.

This expresses your belief that, if Kristina keeps searching for a job, she's going to find one at some point.

--

> 4) Kristina has found a job in the end.

Again this is not correct with present tense; it can be used the same ways as sentence 3 can and with the same meaning.  You could write either of the following:

> Kristina found a job in the end.
>
> Kristina will find a job in the end.

--

If I just found out that Kristina got a job, and am presenting the news to someone I don't think knows, I'd be most likely to say:

> Did you hear that Kristina finally got a job?

"Did you know" is correct, but doesn't have quite the same connotation. "Did you hear" is saying "Has anyone told you this yet?" and is a more natural way of saying things like this.  "Did you know" would more likely be used for interesting facts, like "Did you know that dinosaurs actually had feathers?"

Answer (score 3):

"Kristina has found a job at last" is the most natural of the above.

An adverb usually precedes the verb it modifies, so #2 should be, "Kristina has finally found a job." With that change, #1 and #2 would sound equally good to a native English speaker and would mean pretty much the same thing.

"Eventually" does not mean the same thing as "finally". "Eventually" is normally used only with the future tense. You might say, "I hope that Kristina will eventually find a job".

Likewise, "in the end" is normally used with the simple past tense. "Kristina found a job in the end."

Comment: +1 for excellent point about "eventually" being more likely to occur in reference to *non-present*. I think *"Two years after graduating, Kristina eventually found a job last month"* sounds fine, but I'm a bit less keen on *"...Kristina is eventually starting work today"*, for example.

Answer (score -1):

If the question refers to Kristina’s job, then you don’t necessarily need to repeat it in the answer. See below

> Q: Did Kristina find a job?
>
> A: Yes, she did.
>
> A: Yes, she finally did.

Or in general: Kristina finally found a job.